# Evernote PHP API getNoteContent failes with uncaught exception

Tags: php, evernote

Here's my code:

```
try {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['E_TOKEN'])) {
        $oauth_data  = $oauth_handler->authorize($key, $secret, $callback);

        $token = $oauth_data['oauth_token'];

        $_SESSION['E_TOKEN'] = $token;
    }
    else
        $token = $_SESSION['E_TOKEN'];

    $reason = $_GET['reason'];

    $client = new \Evernote\Client(array('token' => $token, 'sandbox' => true));

    $advancedClient = $client->getAdvancedClient();

    switch ($reason) {
        case 'update':

            $noteGuid = $_GET['guid'];

            $noteStore = $advancedClient->getNoteStore();

            $note = $noteStore->getNoteContent(array('token' => $token), $noteGuid, true, false, false, false);

    }

} catch (Evernote\Exception\AuthorizationDeniedException $e) {
    //If the user decline the authorization, an exception is thrown.
    echo "Declined";
}
```

Here's the exception:

[Sat Apr 30 10:44:55.256042 2016] [:error] [pid 27190:tid 139957362468608] [client 216.104.244.35:32700] PHP Warning:  strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Thrift/StringFunc/Core.php on line 36
[Sat Apr 30 10:44:55.599976 2016] [:error] [pid 27190:tid 139957362468608] [client 216.104.244.35:32700] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'EDAM\Error\EDAMUserException' in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php:3202\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php(717): EDAM\UserStore\UserStore_getNoteStoreUrl_result->read(Object(Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol))\n#1 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php(678): EDAM\UserStore\UserStoreClient->recv_getNoteStoreUrl()\n#2 [internal function]: EDAM\UserStore\UserStoreClient->getNoteStoreUrl(Array)\n#3 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Evernote/Store/Store.php(38): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#4 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Evernote/AdvancedClient.php(69): Evernote\Store\Store->__call('getNoteStoreUrl', Array)\n#5 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Evernote/AdvancedClient.php(69): Evernote\S in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/EDAM/UserStore/UserStore.php on line 3202

Note the error log entry for Core.php at line 36 expecting a string instead of an array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: > Note the error log entry for Core.php at line 36 expecting a string instead of an array. >
That's a warning, fatal error follows. What's at UserStore.php:3202 (and other lines if necessary)?

Comment: Line 3202 of Core.php is:  if ($ftype == TType::STRUCT) {  
   --->      $this->userException = new \EDAM\Error\EDAMUserException();  
            $xfer += $this->userException->read($input);  
          } else {  
            $xfer += $input->skip($ftype);  
          }